# Unexpected token 'UpdateOptions.ExpandFull'

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-analysis-services

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/add-a-data-source-to-tabular-model-analysis-services-amo-tom

i am trying to update the Database connectionstring changes:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$newConnectionString = "Connection Timeout=60;User Id=SOME_NEW_ID;Data Source=10.10.19.10;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8"

 $svr = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$svr.Connect("server1.domain.com")

$svr.databases[1].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString
$svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull)
```

But i am getting errors:

> Unexpected token 'UpdateOptions.ExpandFull' in expression or
>   statement.

if i do regular Update():

```
$svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update()
```

i get this:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource] does not
>   contain a method named 'Update'

and if i try `SaveChanges()`:

```
$svr.Databases[1].Model.SaveChanges()
```

I get this error:

> The following exception occurred while retrieving member
>   "SaveChanges": "Encountered an invalid type for a default value."

if i try just `ExpandFull`

```
$svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update(ExpandFull)
```

i get

> Unexpected token 'ExpandFull' in expression or statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the way that you specify the enum for the update.

You are working directly with .NET types and you have to understand / know where a given enum belongs. In this case the UpdateOptions lives in the Microsoft.AnalysisServices namespace

**Updated**

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$newConnectionString = "Connection Timeout=60;User Id=SOME_NEW_ID;Data Source=10.10.19.10;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8"

$svr = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$svr.Connect("server1.domain.com")

$svr.databases[1].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString
$svr.Databases[1].Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)
```

Comment: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource] does not contain a method
named 'Update'.

Comment: The update should be executed on the model. See my updated answer.

Comment: even with that, i get error: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Update": "Encountered an invalid type for a default value. ....At $svr.Databases[1].model.Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Update ..

Comment: btw, i have also tried this: $svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update, and it doesnt print out an error or even anything, and i checked the dataabse, but the new connection string didnt take effect...

Comment: Try the newly updated (again) version. The update method exists on the database also.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!

Comment: do you want to update the other question with this answer? so i can resolve it and give you answer credit as well :)

Comment: Did that - wanna close the Print question also or do you want to keep that open?

Comment: Done :) thank you very much for your extraordinary help!

Comment: Thank you for not giving up on me 

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is **primarily a *syntax* problem**:

> ```
> $svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull)
> ```

The above is a .NET *method call*, which PowerShell parses in [*expression* mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), which causes `UpdateOptions.ExpandFull` to report a syntax error.

In expression mode:

- references to *types* such as `UpdateOptions` must be enclosed in `[...]`; e.g., `[UpdateOptions]`
- references to *static members* of that type must be referenced via the `::` operator; e.g. `[UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull`

That said, you must:

- either: use the *full* type name, `[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull`, as in [Mötz' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53251688/45375).
- or, in PSv5+: by placing a `using namespace Microsoft.AnalysisServices` statement at the start of the script, you can make the more concise `[UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull` work.

**PowerShell offers a more convenient alternative**, however: you can simply **specify the enumeration value's *symbolic name* as a *string*** - `'ExpandFull'` -  and PowerShell will automatically perform the conversion for you:

```
$svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update('ExpandFull')
```

You don't even need to know the enumeration's type name for this to work (though, if you do know it, using it in a language-aware editor such as Visual Studio Code can provide you with IntelliSense).